# SQL to bring result by month and year with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I was trying to create a SQL into a monthly/yearly result. I'm counting the quantity of Documents with determined Statuses.
I already a SQL that brings part of what i need.
**Here's a short example:**

```
 SELECT _waiting.wt, _concluded.cc
 FROM tb_status as st
 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT count(*) as wt
    FROM tb_status as st
    LEFT JOIN tb_document as dc ON st.iddocument = dc.iddocument
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM tb_status as stt
        WHERE stt.iddocument=st.iddocument
        AND stt.idstatus > st.idstatus)
    AND status LIKE '%Waiting%') as _waiting ON st.iddocument = st.iddocument
 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT count(*) as cc
    FROM tb_status as st
    LEFT JOIN tb_document as dc ON st.iddocument = dc.iddocument
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM tb_status as stt
        WHERE stt.iddocument=st.iddocument
        AND stt.idstatus > st.idstatus)
    AND status LIKE '%Concluded%') as _concluded ON st.iddocument = st.iddocument
 GROUP BY _waiting.wt, _concluded.cc
```

**This SQL brings the exactely result of how many Documents i have with these two Status (Concluded and Waiting). Like this example:**

```
+-----------+-----------------+
|    wt     |       cc        |
+-----------+-----------------+
| 2         | 2               |
+-----------+-----------------+
```

---

Then i made a research to bring that results with Month and Year. My table has a data for each Status. I made this SQL:

```
SELECT to_char(datestatus,'Mon') AS month, extract(year from datestatus) as year, COUNT (*) as count, 
 FROM tb_status as st 
 LEFT JOIN tb_document as dc ON st.iddocument = dc.iddocument 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM tb_status as stt
        WHERE stt.idprocess=st.idprocess
        AND stt.idstatus > st.idstatus
        )
 GROUP BY year, month
```

**This one bring a result like this example:**

```
+-----------+-----------------+------------------+
|   month   |      year       |     count        |
+-----------+-----------------+------------------+
| Nov       | 2016            | 1                |
+-----------+-----------------+------------------+
| Dec       | 2016            | 1                |
+-----------+-----------------+------------------+
| Mar       | 2017            | 2                |
+-----------+-----------------+------------------+
```

But i when i try to increment this last SQL to bring the Status, i get errors or get multiple lines with wrong results.

> **P.S.:** *This "WHERE NOT EXISTIS ()" is a method to take into consideration the latest status from each Document (since its always begin with "Waiting"
>   and pass trough others until get "Concluded")*

---

**Is there a simple way to mix these two SQL into a new one? Any tips? I need something like this example:**

```
+-----------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
|   month   |      year       |     wt           |        cc        |
+-----------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
| Nov       | 2016            | 1                | 0 (or null)      |
+-----------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
| Dec       | 2016            | 0 (or null)      | 1                |
+-----------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
| Mar       | 2017            | 1                | 1                |
+-----------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Edit your question and show what your data structure looks like.  The queries look more complicated than needed for the stated purpose.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks. Yes, i was planning bring my tables and the full (or part of) SQL to ask if there's a better way to get the same result. Thanks for your answer btw.. i'll check it out and see how it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is way more complicated than I think it needs to be.  The following gets the most recent status for each document:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (st.iddocument) . . .
FROM tb_status st JOIN
     tb_document dc
     ON st.iddocument = dc.iddocument
ORDER BY st.iddocument, st.idstatus DESC;
```

You can then aggregate the status values using a subquery:

```
SELECT SUM( (status LIKE '%Waiting%')::int) as waiting,
       SUM( (status LIKE '%Concluded%')::int) as Concluded   
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (st.iddocument) . . ..
      FROM tb_status st JOIN
           tb_document dc
           ON st.iddocument = dc.iddocument
      ORDER BY st.iddocument, st.idstatus DESC
     ) s;
```

And you can easily add dates:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', datestatus) as yyyymm,
       SUM( (status LIKE '%Waiting%')::int) as waiting,
       SUM( (status LIKE '%Concluded%')::int) as Concluded   
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (st.iddocument) st.*  -- Are other columns needed?
      FROM tb_status st JOIN
           tb_document dc
           ON st.iddocument = dc.iddocument
      ORDER BY st.iddocument, st.idstatus DESC
     ) s
GROUP BY yyyymm
ORDER BY yyyymm;
```